# How to check for DbContext class when running command using NuGet on Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/radpZ.png)I am running this command on the package-manager console, but I can't see whether it has executed well. Where do I check if it executed well? Here is my command on the package-manager console?

```
scaffold-DBContext "Data Source="(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Catalog=eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer-OutputDir Models
```

Here is my connectionString below

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=eNtsaOnlineRegistration; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: follow: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: @Hamed I followed and used the link on my command, cant able to see new DbContext class  under my Model folder. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Is your directory `Model` or `Models`?

Comment: directory is Models

Comment: Are you sure about your `connectionString` prperties?!

Comment: Please view my ConnectionString

Comment: Does `eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB` database exist ?!

Comment: Yes Hamed it does and has table columns with data.

Comment: Try `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold ... ` instead of `Scaffold-DbContext ...`

Comment: Still no luck with new command, can this means my project is corrupt? i dont know now what could be an issue